# ld: file not found: Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Tags: ios, xcode7

After switching from Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7.0, I am getting the following error :

ld: file not found: Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Answer (score 2):

This got fixed after I clicked on  "Update to recommended project settings" in the Debug panel accepted the following updates

Build Settings
Target  - Adopt 'Product Bundle Identifier' build setting
Project  - Turn on 'Enable Testability' When Debugging